# Disambiguate [tarfile]

Tags: discussion, tag-disambiguation

It appears that 61/66 [tarfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tarfile) questions are related to Python's tarfile module, but the tag excerpt doesn't suggest that at all. Should we fix up the other 5 (which all refer to actual tarfiles in the more general sense) and change the wiki? Or should there be a new tag for *Python*'s tarfile?

Comment: I'd generally be in favor of making [tag:tarfile] Python-specific, but how should non-Python questions be tagged? It looks like [tag:tar] is for the actual *program* (which is fine for bash script questions) but what if you wanted to ask about tar files in the context of, say, PHP? The [tag:tar] tag could be used as a "generic" tag (in which case, perhaps the tag wiki should be updated to indicate this), or various language-specific tags could be created. Personally, I'd lean towards the former option unless a language has a specific API for handling tar files built-in (like Python does).

Comment: @GoBusto: I think a single other `tar-files` tag might be doable. It's not worth it to create four or five tags for five questions.

Answer (score 4):

I would make, if we need it, a single [python-tarfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-tarfile) to refer to the module. That would prevent confusions and make the tag unambigous. Then, do we really need a tarfile tag for all questions about... tar files? I don't picture a question about the tar file format being on topic, also, for a programmers point of view, it isn't very relevant that is a tar file, a gz file, or  file you are dealing with. As long as you specify in the question the module/library you are using and use those as tags, or you are using the tar binary, should be enough.

Comment: I disagree, we definitely need a tag for the tar format itself. You're saying to instead use the tag related to the library used for dealing with the file... but what if I'm implementing my own library instead of using an existing one ?

Comment: @AndréDaniel language your library is developed?

Comment: The language tag alone would be pretty useless since only a small subset of the language's experts will also be experts in the domain of whatever file format I'm dealing with, so a tag specifically for that file format is also required. Plus, we have tags for major protocols like HTTP, IMAP, etc... so why not have one for tar files as well ?

Comment: @AndréDaniel lets do this exersice, ask a question were the tarfile tag as sole tag of the question would be valid. I scaned through the ones already asked, and none fits the category. So, instead of trying to argue that we need the tag, maybe it would be more desirable that you show that we actually need it.

Comment: @Braiam: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17917982 is just about there already; the fact that it's using C++ or trying to parse HTML is irrelevant for most purposes. http://stackoverflow.com/q/16166592 cannot use a library tag, and tagging it with nothing but [java] is silly. http://stackoverflow.com/q/14202414 is similar after rephrasing to avoid closure. 3 out of 5 ain't bad.

Comment: @NathanTuggy [How do I extract a tar.Z file in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16166592) is not about uncompressing a tar file, but a .z file (whatever that is), tar file format isn't relevant (he can deal with plain tar already "I can extract the zip, **tar**, tar.gz and tar.bz"). [java library to read/write sparse tar files](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14202414) is just off topic (recommend or find a book, **tool, software library**, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow). Still not seeing the need of a tag for the file format itself.

Comment: @Braiam: I did say after rephrasing to avoid closure, which I think can be done. Well spotted on the first one, though.